# Pandas - Selecting multiple dataframe criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns and I need to set the criteria to access specific values from two different columns. I'm able to do it successfully on one column as shown here:

```
status_filter = df[df['STATUS'] == 'Complete']
```

But I'm struggling to specify values from two columns. I've tried something like this but get errors:

```
status_filter = df[df['STATUS'] == 'Complete' and df['READY TO INVOICE'] == 'No']
```

It may be a simple answer, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: What errors do you get ?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has two very small errors: 1) need parentheses for two or more criteria and 2) you need to use the ampersand between your criteria:

```
status_filter = df[(df['STATUS'] == 'Complete') & (df['READY TO INVOICE'] == 'No')]
```

Comment: For providing an explanation and code instead of _just_ code +1

Answer (score 1):

```
status_filter = df.ix[(df['STATUS'] == 'Complete') & (df['READY TO INVOICE'] == 'No'),]
```

ur welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
status_filter = df[(df['STATUS'] == 'Complete') &  (df['READY TO INVOICE'] == 'No')]
```

Comment: You have a typo. `*` should be `&`